# How to enforce i18n locale slugs and achieve i18n consistency upon reload in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, next.js

I'm using [`next-translate`](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate). By default, my routes are recognized as follows:

```
/about         <---
/de/about
/es/about
```

but I'd like to enforce a locale for **all** paths:

```
/en/about      <---
/de/about
/es/about
```

Here's my config:

**next.config.js**

```js
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

module.exports = nextTranslate({
    ...
    i18n: {
        localeDetection: false,
        locales: ['en', 'de', 'es'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
    }
});
```

**i18n.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    locales: ['en', 'de', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    pages: {
        '*': ['common']
    },
    interpolation: {
        prefix: '${',
        suffix: '}',
    },
    loadLocaleFrom: (locale, namespace) =>
        import(`./translations/${locale}/${namespace}`).then((m) => m.default),
}
```

Note that I also have a lang change component that persists the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie. As such, I would expect that when I access `/about` and my `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie had previously been set to `de`, the router would redirect me to `/de/about`. **But it does not**. It stays at `/about` and rewrites the cookie to `en`...

Here's current `pages` folder structure:

```
...
pages/
  _app.tsx
  _document.tsx
  about.tsx
  ...
```

Do I need to restructure it to this?

```
pages/
  _app.tsx
  _document.tsx
  [lang]/         <---
    about.tsx
    ...
```

If so, what would be the next step?

- Parse the preferred locale through `useRouter()`
- Parse the `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie
- Parse the `lang` slug

and then decide which has higher precedence? Where should I do that? In `_app.tsx` / some HOC?

Do I need any `rewrites` or `redirects` in my `next.config.js` or should I handle these dynamically through `Router.push`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fact that the persisted `NEXT_LOCALE` cookie doesn't automatically redirect based on its value is because you have explicitly disabled it by setting [`localeDetection: false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#disabling-automatic-locale-detection). This affects the header-based redirection as well as the cookie-based one.

Simply removing it from your `next.config.js` should solve that issue.

---

There's no built-in way to force the default locale on all paths. However, there are a couple of workarounds that could help with prefixing the default locale on the URL.

##### Workaround #1: Set default locale to `default`, and redirect in middleware

As documented in the [i18n Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#prefixing-the-default-locale) documentation, add a new "dummy" locale named `default` and set it as the default locale. Note that this locale won't actually be used, it will simply allow us to have the `en` locale always prefixed on its paths.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['default', 'en', 'de', 'es'],
        defaultLocale: 'default'
    }
}
```

Next, create a `middleware` file to redirect to the `/en` prefix if a request is made to the `default` locale.

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export function middleware(request) {
    const shouldHandleLocale = !PUBLIC_FILE.test(request.nextUrl.pathname)
        && !request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') 
        && request.nextUrl.locale === 'default'

    if (shouldHandleLocale) {
        const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
        url.pathname = `/en${request.nextUrl.pathname}`
        return NextResponse.redirect(url)
    }

    return undefined
}
```

##### Workaround #2: Shallow routing to prefixed path on the client-side

Alternatively, you could check for the default locale and set it explicitly in the URL on first mount through `router.push`.

Let's assume the following custom `useDefaultLocale` hook that abstracts the logic to be re-used.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const useDefaultLocale = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.locale === router.defaultLocale) {
            router.push(`/${router.locale}${router.asPath}`, undefined, {
                locale: false,
                shallow: true // Optionally add this if you don't want to rerun data fetching methods
            });
        }
    }, [router.asPath]);
};
```

Which could then be used in your pages or `_app.js`.

```js
import { useDefaultLocale } from '<path-to>/use-default-locale';

const AboutPage = () => {
    useDefaultLocale()

    return <>About Page</>;
};
```

Comment: Looks promising, thank you! I would surely need to reuse such redirects -- what would such a custom hook look like? Also, could I do this in `getServerSideProps`? I would like to let search engines know that all my routes are indeed localized (even the landing page `/` itself).

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't find a way to do this on the server-side (with either `redirects` or `getServerSideProps`), as there's no easy way to differentiate `/en/*` from `/*`. Maybe you could look into a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) setup to have it done on the server.

Comment: Thank you. What about the custom hook -- got any example or a link? Not a generic one -- something that relates to the `router`, if possible. Thanks

Comment: @JoeSorocin I've updated my answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was very helpful