# next-translate show default language

Tags: url, routes, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I would like the language to always be displayed in url, but next-transate not shows default one

Was looking for a simple solution like this, **but it doesn't work**

```
{
    "locales": ["en", "ru"],
    "defaultLocale": "ru",
    "showDefaultLocale": true, 
    "pages": {
        "*": ["navbar", "common", "title"],
        "/auth": ["auth"],
        "/404": ["404"]
    }
}
```

Is there any working solution for example with next.config.js rewrites?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to enforce i18n locale slugs and achieve i18n consistency upon reload in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67245407/1870780) (second part of the answer)?

Comment: @juliomalves just what i need, thank you very much